# Error Android Studio:No dex files created while using Google's Calendar API

Tags: android-studio, google-calendar-api

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.calendarquickstart"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev210-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

}
```

I am trying to use google API for calendar but I am getting following error while running the app"

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: **No dex files
> >     created at**
> >     C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\CalendarQuickstart\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\guava-jdk5-17.0_bbc68f1b67df2c58337cd00757b7bfd105bb5573"

I am following the steps from this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android#step_1_acquire_a_sha1_fingerprint)

What changes need to be done in gradle file for running this app?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the multidex support in your build.gradle file as stated in [Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

*Additional reading:*

Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536—including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code. In the context of computer science, the term Kilo, K, denotes 1024 (or 2^10). Because 65,536 is equal to 64 X 1024, this limit is referred to as the '64K reference limit'.

Getting past this limit requires that you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX file, known as a multidex configuration.

Comment: I tried this but still I end up with same error as before